# Debugging an .out object, compiled with cmake, using GDB

Tags: c++, cmake, gdb

I have a large C++ project that is compiled using a cmake file (that for the moment I couldn't hope to recreate/compile using g++), and even though I run it in debug mode, i.e. using in terminal

```
cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug ..
```

I don't get any .out file I can run GDB with... what am I doing wrong? New to C++ development. Any advice would be appreciated. Running VSCode on Ubuntu.

My main goal is to try and find performance bottlenecks in the program, for which I've found valgrind/gdb/gprof should help? Any tips?

Comment: after your CMake command, use `cmake --build`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cmake isn't compiler, it creates makefiles for your platform, then you have to use compiler to build project( basically make -j for gcc, where j amount of cores, or nmake for msvc compiler)

Comment: You mean like  "make" ?

Comment: cmake basically creates makefile for your project, with all listed dependencies and parameters from cmake file. then you use command "make" to build project depending on your platform and compiler

Comment: Cheers, but there is some cmake option I need to activate such that I get a build file that'll give me a debug-able .out file upon building right?

Comment: yep -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug, -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release - for optimized release version, blank will get you non-debug-able non-optimized version

Comment: Phrase `then you have to use compiler to build project` isn't quite correct: the project is built using **build tool** (`make`, `nmake` or `msvc`, as you noted). *Compiler* (e.g. `g++`) is invoked by the build tool during building.